# Getting a property for an attribute

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

So here is my issue. I need to get the mailbox server for the system mailbox generating the OAB in Exchange 2013.

When I do this in the Exchange Powershell for one OAB it works. Here is what I do :

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$a = Get-OfflineAddressBook
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$a.generatingmailbox.name
SystemMailbox{bb558c35-97f1-4cb9-8ff7-d53741dc928c}
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>get-mailbox -anr $a.generatingmailbox.name -Arbitration | select servername
```

This works well.

When I use a foreach it does not work.

```
@(Get-OfflineAddressBook) | foreach `
{
    $_.generatingmailbox.Name #this is empty

}
```

I use the foreach in order to retrieve the info for all the OABs.

Is this normal ? Could you suggest some workarounds ?

Thanks,

Comment: Try to `Name` -> `name`.

Comment: Nope it does not work.